# How to select the first of two classes in javascript/coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a Coffeescript file that scrolls to the first error of type .has-error, or type .alert-danger, that appears on the page.

```js
$(document).ajaxComplete ->
  scroll_to_error()

@scroll_to_error = ->
  if $('.alert-danger:visible:first').length > 0
    $('html, body').animate { scrollTop: $('.alert-danger:visible:first').offset().top - 220 }, 'fast'

  if $('.has-error:visible:first').length > 0
    $('html, body').animate { scrollTop: $('.has-error:visible:first').offset().top - 220 }, 'fast' 
  return
```

However, I want to scroll to the first element with class either .has-error or .alert-danger. Is there a way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to combine the two class selectors:

> **jQuery( "selector1, selector2, selectorN" )**
>   [...]
>   The order of the DOM elements in the returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in document order.

Also, the accessor version of [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) will

> Get the current coordinates of the first element, [...]

so you don't need to worry about including `:first` in your selectors.

So something like this:

```
$errors = $('.alert-danger:visible, .has-error:visible')
if $errors.length
  $('html, body').animate { scrollTop: $errors.offset().top - 220 }, 'fast'
```

should do the trick. Note that `$errors.length` should be zero if there aren't any matches and non-zero if there are and `0` is still falsey in CoffeeScript so a simple `if $errors.length` is sufficient, you can still say `if $errors.length > 0` if you want though.